# How can I use SQLCMD with Windows Authentication (-E,) but without elevated permissions

Tags: sql, windows, ssms, sqlcmd

I'm going to create a script to execute numerous SQL files. I've chose to use SQLCMD instead of ADODB because it provides logging information quickly, and we're executing T-SQL. I'm testing out SQLCMD.exe **before putting it into the script**.

Connecting to the database using SQLCMD.exe, I utilize -E for Windows Authentication. This means that I need to use my network account, which does not have elevated access on any given machine. However, SQLCMD.exe requires elevated access in order to execute a query, otherwise I receive the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file (Reason: Access is denied).

After running the following command:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S <SQLSERVER,PORT> -d <DATABASE> -i scriptfile.sql -o scriptfile.log -E
```

How can I utilize SQLCMD.exe with elevated local permissions (Administrator) but use Windows Authentication to connect to the server (using a non-Administrator account)? I'd prefer not to change any permissions of SQLCMD.exe, as there may be multiple people that use this script that I'm not keen on informing them of this prior instruction.

Comment: what was the full command you tried?

Comment: I think the error you are seeing is related to a script file or log file you are referencing.  Not whether or not you are using windows auth.  Can you post the full command to give us a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Sure here is the full command
sqlcmd.exe -S <SQLSERVER,PORT> -d <DATABASE> -i scriptfile.sql -o scriptfile.log -E

Comment: Where's the VBScript? That is the raw `sqlcmd` not the VBScript you used to execute it.

Comment: I'm testing the sqlcmd before introducing it into the script.

Comment: And what path are you running the command from when you test it?  Does the non-administrator running the command have access to read from `scriptfile.sql` and access to write to `scriptfile.log`?  Most commands generally default to the current working directory.

Comment: That was it! I was storing the script in the same folder as SQLCMD.exe as testing purposes, and wasn't giving the user permissions. These scripts are on a network drive, so I can use pushd/popd to access with the VBScript. Thank you for the help, it was a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What path are you running the command from when you test it? Does the non-administrator running the command have access to read from `scriptfile.sql` and access to write to `scriptfile.log`? Most commands generally default to the current working directory.

Comment: It wasn't that I did not have access to SQLCMD. As Bacon Bits stated above, I was attempting to execute a script that the non-Administrator user did not have access to.