# Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C:

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a python script that runs a few sql scripts using subprocesses.

```
branch_path = "C:/devel/branch" #path used in command
command_process = subprocess.Popen(
['sqlcmd', '-E', '-V1', '-S', 'MYPC', '-i', branch_path +"/DatabaseScripts/restore_db_mss.sql"],
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
shell=True
)
command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]
print command_output
```

I get this error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C: (Reason: Access is denied).
```

I tried giving my machine the correct permissions but nothing worked. I tried swtching to the service to admin as suggested by others but that is not working either. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You need to surround the path with quotes.

Comment: @pmbAustin I tried using the entire path enclosed in brackets instead of concatenating the branch path, still throw the same error.

Comment: May you try reading the path as raw string? `['sqlcmd', '-E', '-V1', '-S', 'MYPC', '-i', r"C:/devel/branch/DatabaseScripts/restore_db_mss.sql"]` On the other hand. Start cmd [right click] "as admin" Also check if the sql server service has permission to "C:\". Does it work in cmd without python?

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305856/how-can-i-use-sqlcmd-with-windows-authentication-e-but-without-elevated-perm ?

Comment: @user2853437 nope doesnt work

Comment: I don't think you understood... the path needs to be quoted.  You have this .... 

branch_path +"/DatabaseScripts/restore_db_mss.sql" ....  but what you need is something like this: ... "\"" + branch_path + "/DatabaseScripts/restore_db_mss.sql\"" ... Where \" is an escaped quote character that puts the actual quote in the value being passed.